# Small utility to edit excel files

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-office

I want to edit my excel file. I don't have Microsoft Office installed. The files include `xls` and `xlsx`. I would like to know about the smallest utility available to download. It should not be online like Google Docs or Office Online.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [portable version of Gnumeric](http://portableapps.com/apps/office/gnumeric_portable) I have used before when needing to edit an Excel file on a system without Office.

I would suggest LibreOffice Calc as well but it seems you can only get the [full suite](http://portableapps.com/apps/office/libreoffice_portable) which is almost the size of a full CD.